# Redefining brackets

Tags: macros, delimiters

In my thesis I'm working with a lot of brackets around fractions and every time I have to use
`\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)`. It can get really confusing if i have a long equation and a lot of fractions.

Is there a way to redefine `(` such that every time I type `(`, it automatically gets interpreted as `\left(`?

I tried to redefine it as a macro, but it doesn't seem to work with brackets.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in solutions provided by packages like »[bropd](http://ctan.org/pkg/bropd)«, »[esdiff](http://ctan.org/pkg/esdiff)« or »[physics](http://ctan.org/pkg/physics)«

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Redefining the meaning of the parentheses, `(` and `)`, may be rather dangerous since they can occur in so many contexts, even in math material. There may also be situations where you would *not* want the parentheses to be enlarged automatically.

Rather than redefining the meaning of the parentheses, you may want to consider defining a new macro called, say, \pfrac (short for "parenthetical fraction", I suppose) that encloses the fraction expression automatically in auto-sized parentheses:

```
\newcommand{\pfrac}[2]{\left( \frac{#1}{#2} \right)}
```

This will let you write expressions such as `\pfrac{1}{2}`. Observe that this is marginally simpler (and, importantly, less prone to "accidents" caused by omitted opening and/or closing parentheses) than writing `(\frac{1}{2})`.

If you go this route, i.e., have lots and lots of fractional expressions encased in auto-sized parentheses, I would recommend you also load the `mleftright` package and issue the command `\mleftright` in the preamble. Doing so gets rid of the extra space inserted in various situations by `\left` and `\right`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\pfrac}[2]{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}\right)}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright
\begin{document}
\[ 
\pfrac{1}{2} \pfrac{3}{4} \pfrac{5}{6} 
\textstyle \pfrac{1}{2} \pfrac{3}{4} \pfrac{5}{6} 
\]
\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum**, prompted by a comment by egreg: One could also utilize the macro `\genfrac` of the `amsmath` package to define a fraction macro that automatically surrounds its contents with a pair of parentheses. For instance, one could define

```
\newcommand{\qfrac}[2]{\genfrac {(} {)} {} {} {#1} {#2}}
```

Substituting this macro in place of `\pfrac` in the MWE above yields:

[image]

One notes that the parentheses are now set very close to the fraction expressions. You may (or may not) prefer this look to that produced by the `\pfrac` macro given above.

Comment: There is already `\genfrac` that can make fractions with suitable delimiters, so defining `\pfrac` is best done in terms of `\genfrac`.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this suggestion. I've provided an addendum that shows how one could use the `\genfrac` approach. The parentheses end up being typeset much closer to the fractions they enclose than if one uses the `\pfrac` macro set up in the initial part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A first attempt (without restriction to math mode etc.):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\let\lb=(
\let\rb=)

\catcode`\(=\active
\def({\left\lb}
\catcode`\)=\active
\def){\right\rb}

$$
\lb\frac{a}{b}\rb
\quad
(\frac{a}{b})
$$


\end{document}
```

Comment: This will break many things. Maybe making `(` and `)` math active is less risky. I can't recommend it, though.

Comment: @egreg Certainly, Mico's solution is safer. But if the OP really needs \left-like brackets, additional restrictions in definition and suggested limitations of usage can be added.

Comment: And what do you do if you need `\makebox(0,0){text}`? Or, more simply, parentheses in text?