# New \left \right delimiters

Tags: math-mode, equations, delimiters

Can I introduce new delimiter symbols to use with `\left` and `\right`?
For example I would like to do

```
\begin{equation}
\left\harpoonleft something \right\harpoonright
\end{equation}
```

I would then like the size of the symbols to be dependent on the size of `something` between the symbols.

How would I do such a thing?

Comment: I think you *can* redefine `\left` and `\right` but I'm not sure if it is a good idea... [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2610/22492) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134401/redefining-brackets) answer might help you.

Comment: A symbol can go after `\left` or `\right` only if scalable versions of the symbol are available as part of the font.

Comment: The mathtools \DeclarePairedDelimiter is probably easiest.  One could do it from scratch using graphics \resizebox.

Comment: @JohnKormylo that wont do any resizing when whats between the delimiters is large. But that's probably because of what egreg said.

Answer (score 8):

I mean that the qeustion mentions the harpoons, no arrows. Because there is no harpoon part in common math symbols and the `\resizebox` creates the harpoon marks deformed, I suggest another solution: to draw the harpoon parts as PDF code using `\pdfliteral`. The rest is simply `\vrule`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\leftharpoonpart  {\pdfliteral{q 0 0 m 0 -2.1 -1.2 -2.8 -1.5 -3 c 1 j .4 w S Q}}
\def\rightharpoonpart {\pdfliteral{q 0 0 m 0 -2.1  1.2 -2.8  1.5 -3 c 1 j .4 w S Q}}

\def\encloseharpoons#1{\setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle{#1}$}%
   \mathop{\,\vrule height\ht0 depth\dp0
   \kern-.2pt \raise\ht0\vbox to0pt{\vss\leftharpoonpart\kern.1pt}%
   \copy0
   \raise\ht0\vbox to0pt{\vss\rightharpoonpart\kern.1pt}\kern-.2pt\vrule\,}%
   \nolimits
}
\begin{document}

$$a \cdot \encloseharpoons{\int_a^b} + \encloseharpoons{1\over2}^2$$

\end{document}
```

Of course, no special packages are needed. The result is

[image: harpoon]

And the detail:

[image: harpoon detail]

You have to use `pdflatex` or `lualatex`. When `xelatex` is used you need to add the definition:

```
\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Tikz to create your delimeters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\leftdelim}[2]% #1 = height, #2 = depth
{\tikz[baseline]{\draw[color=red,arrows={-latex}](0,-#2)--(0,#1);}}

\newcommand{\rightdelim}[2]% #1 = height, #2 = depth
{\tikz[baseline]{\draw[color=red,arrows={latex-}](0,-#2)--(0,#1);}}

\newlength{\MyHeight}
\newlength{\MyDepth}
\newsavebox{\MyBox}

\newcommand{\mydelim}[1]% #1 = text to be enclosed
{\savebox{\MyBox}{$\displaystyle #1$}% get size of box
\settoheight{\MyHeight}{\usebox{\MyBox}}%
\settodepth{\MyDepth}{\usebox{\MyBox}}%
\leftdelim{\MyHeight}{\MyDepth}%
\,\usebox{\MyBox}\,%
\rightdelim{\MyHeight}{\MyDepth}}

\begin{document}
\[
\mydelim{\frac{x+a}{x+b}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: delimiters]

If you do NOT want to use tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\newlength{\MyHeight}
\newlength{\MyDepth}
\newlength{\MyDiff}
\newsavebox{\MyBox}

\newcommand{\mydelim}[1]% #1 = text to be enclosed
{\savebox{\MyBox}{$\displaystyle #1$}% get size of box
\settoheight{\MyHeight}{\usebox{\MyBox}}%
\settodepth{\MyDepth}{\usebox{\MyBox}}%
\addtolength{\MyHeight}{\MyDepth}%
\settodepth{\MyDiff}{$\uparrow$}
\addtolength{\MyDiff}{-\MyDepth}
\raisebox{\MyDiff}{\resizebox{\width}{\MyHeight}{$\uparrow$}}%
\,\usebox{\MyBox}\,%
\raisebox{\MyDiff}{\resizebox{\width}{\MyHeight}{$\downarrow$}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\mydelim{\frac{x+a}{x+b}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: resize]

Comment: Erh, `\uparrow` and `\downarrow` already qualify as delimiters so no need for `tikz` or scaling in that case.

Comment: I didn't realize that harpoon referred to a specific shape.  I used arrows because they were easy.

Comment: I notice that this answer hard codes the math style (which I post a patch in a separate answer below). I think it's a minor change, so you can edit this answer and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Or you can accept you own answer.  I don't need the points.

Answer (score 1):

This is an improvement over [John Kormylo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183983/250119) -- it works, but has a small quirk: it hard codes the math style.

What does this mean? Consider for example, with that definition:

```
\[ \mydelim{\frac{x+a}{x+b}} \]

$ \mydelim{\frac{x+a}{x+b}} + \frac{x+a}{x+b} $
```

the second formula is too large, compared to the one outside the custom delimiter.

[image: output]

One way to fix it is to manually add the `\textstyle` command:

```
$ \mydelim{\textstyle \frac{x+a}{x+b}} \frac{x+a}{x+b} $
```

(in this case you don't need the `\displaystyle` at all)

Another way is to modify the command definition as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % ← note the added package

\newcommand{\leftdelim}[2]% #1 = height, #2 = depth
{\tikz[baseline]{\draw[color=red,arrows={-latex}](0,-#2)--(0,#1);}}

\newcommand{\rightdelim}[2]% #1 = height, #2 = depth
{\tikz[baseline]{\draw[color=red,arrows={latex-}](0,-#2)--(0,#1);}}

\newlength{\MyHeight}
\newlength{\MyDepth}
\newsavebox{\MyBox}

\newcommand{\mydelim}[1]% #1 = text to be enclosed
{\text{\savebox{\MyBox}{$#1$}% get size of box
\settoheight{\MyHeight}{\usebox{\MyBox}}%
\settodepth{\MyDepth}{\usebox{\MyBox}}%
\leftdelim{\MyHeight}{\MyDepth}%
\,\usebox{\MyBox}\,%
\rightdelim{\MyHeight}{\MyDepth}}}

\begin{document}
\[ \mydelim{\frac{x+a}{x+b}} \]

$ \mydelim{\frac{x+a}{x+b}} + \frac{x+a}{x+b} $
\end{document}
```

which gives the desired result.

[image: fixed output]

An explanation of the `\text` command may be found at [rotating - Rotated math with correct font size - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286050/rotated-math-with-correct-font-size).